# Displaying data on checkbox checked when there are other checkboxes with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching a list of player names from database and there is a checkbox associated with each player. I am displaying the player names in frontend using loop and code is:

```
 var TeamList = matchDetails.matchData.teamAPlayers.map(function (player) {
        return  '<div class="row">'+
                    '<div class="col-md-10">'+
                        '<li style="list-style-type: none;">'+player.playerName+'</li>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="col-md-2">'+
                        '<label class="switch">' +
                        '<input data-id='+ player._id +' class="player-on-strike" type="checkbox">' +
                        '<span class="slider round">' +
                        '</span>' +
                        '</label>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'
    });
    $("#team-players-list").html(TeamList);
```

All the checkboxes have a common class player-on-strike and data-id is the id of every player which i am fetching from database.

Now i want that if the checkbox is checked the player's name is displayed at some div and if other checkbox is checked the earlier one goes off and new player's name gets displayed in that div.

My code for doing that is:

```
$('body').on('change', '.player-on-strike', function () {
var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("player-on-strike");
    if ($(checkbox.checked == true)){
        var playerOnStrike = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.player-on-strike1').html(playerOnStrike);
    }

});
```

player-on-strike one is the class of the div where i want to display the player's name.[image]

This is the image of player list displayed.

Comment: you can first empty the div and then repopulate it
$('.player-on-strike1').html('');
then 
$('.player-on-strike1').html(playerOnStrike);

Comment: What do you think your `if` is evaluating? `$(checkbox.checked == true)` `checkbox` is a live nodeList of element nodes, which doesn't have a `checked` property, therefore it will never be equal to `true`, will always return `false` and then you're making that Boolean a jQuery Object (for some reason), which is itself truthy by virtue of existing. Can you show your [mcve] code that's actually generated and present in the page, upon which the jQuery is expected to act?

Answer (score 0):

After you line `$("#team-players-list").html(TeamList);` Add following code,

Because after adding dynamic content to html you required to bind the click event.

```
$(".player-on-strike").click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
        $('.player-on-strike1').html($(this).attr('data-id'));
    }
});
```

Try this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zqbtb36a/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".player-on-strike").click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
       $('.player-on-strike1').html($(this).parent().parent().prev().children('li').text());
    }
});
```